# Infinite loop in C counting spaces

Tags: c

I'm writing a program to count spaces and vowels and it didn´t work, I think I did an infinite loop.I'll show you my code:

```
int contar_p(char a[100]) {
    int i = 0, spaces = 1;

    while (a[i] != '\0' && i < 100) {
        if (a[i] == ' ') {
            spaces += 1;
            i++;
        }           

    }
    return spaces;
}

int contar_v(char b[100]) {
    int i = 0, counter = 0;

    while (b[i] != '\0' && i < 100) {
        if (b[i] == 'a' || b[i] == 'e' || b[i] == 'i' || b[i] == 'o' || b[i] == 'u') {
            counter += 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return counter;
}

int main(void){
    char phrase[100];
    int words = 0, vowels = 0;

    printf("write a phrase ");
    gets(phrase);

    palabras = contar_p(phrase);
    vocales = contar_v(phrase);

    printf("%d\n", words);
    printf("%d", vowels);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When do you increase `i` when it is not a space?

Comment: Please detail what you mean by "it didn´t work" and what your input was or could be.

Comment: " I think I did an infinite loop...:.  You don't have to *guess*.  Step through the code in the debugger!

Comment: What is `palabras` and `vocales`?

Comment: i translate into english and forget to translate that

Comment: when i put in the input show me the printf and keep running but nothing appears

Comment: Read the compiler *warnings:* **yourprog.c:(.text.startup+0x8): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.**

Answer (score 1):

The loop

```
while (a[i]!='\0'&&i<100){
    if(a[i]==' '){
        spaces+=1;
        i++;
    }           
}
```

is an infinite loop. Place `i++` outside the `if`. Change it to

```
while (a[i]!='\0'){  // No need of condition i < 100
    if(a[i]==' '){
        spaces+=1;
    }   
    i++;        
}
```

Comment: ...but not *right* outside the loop? Outside the `if` block, surely.

Comment: @WeatherVane; Oops! Sorry. Corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another approach will help you to understand things easier, i'm mean you do know that there are A,E,I,O,U also and not only a,e,i,o,u. You should never use gets instead use fgets, anyway take a look at the following program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void countVowels(char* array){
    int i,j,v;
    i=0;
    int count = 0;
    char vowel[]={'a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U'};

    while(array[i]!='\0'){
        for(v=0;v<10;v++){
            if (array[i]==vowel[v]){
                j=i;
                while(array[j]!='\0'){
                    array[j]=array[j+1];
                    j++;
                }
                count++;
                i--;
                break;
            }
        }
    i++;
  }

  printf("Found %d Vowels\n",count);
}

void contar_p(char a[100]) {
    int i = 0, spaces = 0;

    for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++){
        if(a[i]==' ')
        spaces++;
    }
    printf("Found %d Spaces\n",spaces);
}


int main(void){
    char a[]="aa bb EOU cc ii";
    countVowels(a);
    contar_p(a);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Found 7 Vowels
> Found 4 Spaces
> ```